# ¿A qué se debe el error "TypeError: No se puede llamar al método "getRange" de null. (línea 9, archivo "practicando")

Tags: google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo

Tengo el siguiente código que dependiendo del valor de los dos primeros rangos coloca el valor de un tercer rango o celda en otra pestaña de la misma hoja, pero me arroja el error:

> TypeError: No se puede llamar al método "getRange" de null. (línea 9, archivo "practicando")

---

[image: Código]

La línea 9 es donde hace referencia a la primera celda en este caso D7.

Es un proyecto para realizar el reporte de notas de profesores de una institución tengo 3 hojas una llamada ingreso de estudiantes (contiene datos de los alumnos) la 2da hoja, la hoja maestra (se procesan las notas) una 3a hoja donde se registran las notas finales de cada materia el script debería tomar los datos de la hoja maestra F7 F8 procesarlos y dependiendo al resultado abrir la 3ra hoja y colocar el valor de hoja2 Y15 en f11 de hoja3

Comment: Bienvenido. Usualmente la preguntas que incluyen código mediante una captura de pantalla no son bien recibidas e incluso son votadas negativamente con la siguiente explicación [Te he votado negativamente porque una captura del código no es de ayuda](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2869/). Te sugiero reemplazar la captura de pantalla por el código en forma de texto.

Comment: Coloque el código en la pregunta. Lee: **[cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)**.

Comment: Por otro lado, no está claro cuál es la línea 9, deberías indicarlo. Tampoco está claro si el código lo es parte de un proyecto vinculado y a que tipo de documento lo has vinculado o si se trata de un proyecto independiente.

Comment: Por lo que se puede ver parece que Registrodenotas es null, verificá que la hoja tenga esa pestaña y con ese nombre.

Comment: ok soy nuevo aqui y poco a poco voy aprendiendo a formular las preguntas la linea 9 es donde hace referencia a la primera celda en este caso D7 ; es un proyecto para realizar el reporte de notas de  profesores de una institución tengo 3 hojas una llamada ingreso de estudiantes(contiene  datos  de los alumnos )la 2da hoja,  la hoja maestra( se procesan las notas )  una 3a hoja donde se registran las notas finales de cada materia el  script deberia tomar los datos de la hoja maestra F7 F8 procesarlos y depediendo al resultado abrir la 3ra hoja y colocar el valor de hoja2  Y15   en f11 de hoja3

Comment: lo he mejorado pero aun asi no funciona aqui el otro codigo:

Comment: @ManuelMedina Puede tomar algo de tiempo, paciencia pero si perseveras seguramente tendrás muchas satisfacciones. En cuando a tu comentario previo, la información relevante sobre las preguntas/respuestas debe colocarse directamente en la publicación que corresponde, en otras palabras hay que editar en lugar de comentar. No me queda claro a qué te refieres con que "no funciona aqui el otro código". Si te refieres a que intentaste ejecutar el código en esta página, eso no se puede.

Answer (score 1):

Si la línea `rango = Registrodenotas.getRange('D7');` devuelve el error indicado, se debe a que Registrodenotas tiene null asignado lo cual a su vez se debe a que en la línea anterior no se encontró una hoja con nombre `Registro de Notas`.

Ten presente que Google Apps Script es muy riguroso con las minúsculas y mayúsculas.